# C Segmentation Fault Error Message

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming and I'm creating a client - server program. The client basically calls the functions on the server and the result is basically returned to the client. However, I keep getting a segmentation error when trying to send the contents of a specified directory to the client.

It lists the file names in the directory in the server but they are not returned to the client. After the names of the files are listed an error comes up and the program crashes:
`Segmentation Fault`

**Code:**

```
void three()
{
DIR *mydir;
    if ((mydir = opendir("transfer/")) == NULL) {
    perror("error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct dirent *entry = NULL;

    // returns NULL when dir contents all processed
    while ((entry = readdir(mydir)) != NULL) 
    printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
    strcpy((char *) send_buff, entry->d_name);
    write(connfd, send_buff, strlen((char *) send_buff) + 1);
}
```

Is there any way of fixing this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. And sure, there are ways to fix that. But that would require that you show all the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: @bigjoed  You should enclose in braces these statements     while ((entry = readdir(mydir)) != NULL) { 
    printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
    strcpy((char *) send_buff, entry->d_name);
    write(connfd, send_buff, strlen((char *) send_buff) + 1); } Otherwise this statement strcpy((char *) send_buff, entry->d_name);
 is executed when entry is equal to NULL.

Comment: This has nothing to do with bash. Also, what is `send_buff` ?

Comment: It does, however have a lot to do with bad intentation :(   Thre's a reason I keep complaiing about poor formatting in posted code - this is one reason.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit indentation*, There's*, complaining* :(

Comment: LOL, OK, i also spelt theres rong:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the curly braces around this block of code as currently it's only calling the `printf`. The `strcpy` and `write` will only get called once the loop has finished, by which time the contents of `entry` won't be valid.

```
while ((entry = readdir(mydir)) != NULL)
  {
  printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
  strcpy((char *) send_buff, entry->d_name);
  write(connfd, send_buff, strlen((char *) send_buff) + 1);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

At least you have to enclose in braces the statements after the while statement

```
// returns NULL when dir contents all processed
while ((entry = readdir(mydir)) != NULL)
{ 
    printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
    strcpy((char *) send_buff, entry->d_name);
    write(connfd, send_buff, strlen((char *) send_buff) + 1);
}
```

Otherwise this statement

```
    strcpy((char *) send_buff, entry->d_name);
```

is performed when `entry` is equal to `NULL`.